# How do I programmatically scroll to a specific v-list-item in v-list?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm using Vue/Vuetify and have a `v-list` that is scrollable:

```
<v-layout scrollable ...
  <v-list ...
    <template v-for=id...
      <v-list-item :key=id...
```

Is it possible to programmatically scroll the items so that a particular one is in the visible area of the scrollable list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scroll to any DOM element using plain JavaScript method [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Before that you can give an `id` for each element of your list. By example, this way:

```js
<v-container>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>
      <v-btn
        ref="button"
        block
        color="primary"
        @click="scrollTo"
      >
        scroll to Item-20
      </v-btn>
    </v-col>
    
    <v-col cols="12">
      <v-card>
        <v-list max-height="300" class="overflow-y-auto">
          <v-subheader>ITEMS</v-subheader>
          <v-list-item
             v-for="(item, i) in items"
             :key="i"
             :id="'list-item-' + (item.id + 1)">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
...
data () {
  return {
    items: [],
  }
},
mounted() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    this.items.push({ id: i, text: 'Item-' + (i + 1)})
  }
},
methods: {
  scrollTo() {
    document.getElementById("list-item-20").scrollIntoView()
  }
}
```

Test this [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/yLPYREG).

**P.S.:** there is no `scrollable` prop in [v-layout API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-layout/). At least, in latest v2.6.3.

Comment: Thanks, work like a charm. With the addition of the package `scroll-into-view-if-needed` I got exactly what I wanted. (I was under the impression that scrollIntoView() scrolled the whole window which was not what I wanted.)